# Casting 0.00 decimal fields to null check in APEX

Tags: apex, trigger, code

I'm working on standard page and what is the best way to cast any `0.00` to `null` check? I have a situation where I want to check to see if the decimal value is 0.00 but is that consider to be a best practice if I have something like this:

```
if(reading == 0.00) { //its null }
```

Comment: Can you please provide more context? Where in the controller/extension are you doing this?

Comment: @AdrianLarson:  its more of a generic question or approach then context and I do not have much code to show you other than what I have here... so bascially its a check to see reading is null or not.

Comment: why would you downvote any explanation?

Comment: Not I with the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general verb I tend to for this process is to `elide`:

```
public static Decimal elide(Decimal value)
{
    return (value == 0) ? null : value;
}
```